# Jasny Bootstrap change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

I was looking for a sidebar to my admin template and I wanted to use jasnybootstrap. 
My goal was to resize the content and do not translate out of the screen.

A similar effect is this http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

I hope someone can tell me if it is possible to obtain such a result.

```
<nav id="myNavmenu" class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas" role="navigation">
  <a class="navmenu-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#myNavmenu" data-canvas="body">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1>Jasny Bootstrap starter template</h1>

<p class="lead">Use this fiddle to demonstrate an issue with Jasny Bootstrap or to show an example using Jasny Bootstrap.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k9K5d/13/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I have made it using CSS.

```
#myNavmenu ~ .container {
   padding-left: 10px;
}

#myNavmenu.canvas-slid ~ .container {
   padding-left: 320px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k9K5d/14/

I have made it using Jquery.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/k9K5d/15/

// JS

$(".navbar-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".container").toggleClass("slide");
});

// CSS

.container.slide {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.container {
  padding-left: 320px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k9K5d/15/

You just need to make a change in padding-left property for class 'container'.

Comment: I thank you for the great answer you gave .
The only problem is that once closed the sidebar , the container does not come back off  in large screen